# Do I need commit if i do only selects in aiomysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, transactions

I am using aiomysql (https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql) and have some problems with the unclosed transaction and locking rows. I use AIO connections pool in my application.
I am NOT using SA context managers for transactions.

My questions:

1. If I do only and only SELECT's as I understand there are no locks on rows, So do I need to call wait for conn.commit() or I can skip it if I can skip how MySQL should now what the transaction ends?
2. In the code below, then AIO MySQL start a new transaction? then acquire() connection called or then create cursor called or I should explicitly call "START TRANSACTION"?

[image]

Comment: Please post code, **not images of code**...

Comment: i try but it not well formated (all text in one line)

Comment: usually if you introduce enough empty lines, it will work out.

Comment: does not help - i put text version here - https://gist.github.com/evgenii-malov/96d1b7873aaba0cf6ff2d45ca46f7dee

Answer (score 0):

The commit needs to be inside the try block as you want to be sure to rollback if there is no commit.  However selects do not require commits.

If autocommit is True on your connection then each insert or update is considered a single transaction and implicitly committed. If autocommit is False then you automatically get transactions and must commit after your inserts.  You do not need to call START TRANSACTION if autocommit is false.

If you need to call START TRANSACTION you use conn.begin() documented here:

https://aiomysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#connection

A MySQL transaction is used if you have multiple contingent updates that must all be successful together or rolled back. For example a bank transfer that fails on the second update needs to be rolled back:

- Withdraw money from account A
- Deposit money in account B

You can find a transaction example in the aiomysql github.

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/tree/master/examples